# Java for beginners in netbeans

Tags: java

I'm new in java and I tried to solve this problem, but I struggle to do it

I used For loop however I couldn't solve anything just add the arguments and
I only calculated the 26-week sequence 
with

for(int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
System.out.println(i);

but I get stuck there and cant do more.
my apologies if it is not well done as I am a beginner,

here I post the full exercise

Calculation of a bacteria spread

Create a program bacteriacalculator that calculates the spread of bacteria and shows how many infected and dead people will probably be after a certain time. It is a console application and expects the following entries in the form of program arguments:

Argument 1: The number of infected people when calculations start, an int
 Argument 2: The number of weeks, the calculation has to run, an int
 Argument 3: The weekly increase of infections in percent, so use double
 Argument 4: The mortality rate for this disease in percent, so use double

Your program takes the input mentioned above, checks for the correctness and determines the number of people being infected (will die) week per week.

So, your program should (as an example) be started like:
Viruscalculator 100 26 5,5 3,5
And then produce this output on screen:
[the program should be like this when you run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yzVu.png)
Viruscalculator will calculate with 100 persons at the start and run for 26 weeks with an increase of infections of 25,5% and a mortality of 3,5%:
Hint:

Comment: Please post code and be more specific.

Comment: `double b = 16,6%` **what**? Do you mean `double b = 0.166`? Also, what is `16.6%` and where did your numbers come from? Who told you `2.6%` become paid users? Why does it run for 14 weeks? And why are you trying to write a Java program to solve an excel table? Excel has functions and is capable of doing this.

Comment: yes sorry, i just edited it. Hope it is now understandable.

Comment: Your loop will run exactly 27 times. You need a loop that is based on the second [command line argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) per your requirements. Inside the loop you will need to perform the calculations and generate the required [formatted output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html).

Comment: Do you understand, completely, what the question is asking you to do? If not then you need to break it down into smaller pieces so it's easier to understand. The image is a great hint in what you need to do. Being a beginner is not an excuse for not being able to solve a problem. A teacher will not give you a problem that you are capable of solving, given everything you have learned in the class so far. Like I said, break the question down into smaller parts and solve each part. The first thing you need to do is get the arguments from the command line and store those into well-named variables.

Comment: Try using a pen and paper and writing the problem down and solving it by paper first. This might help you to understand the processes and calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the question and the table properly, I have come to the following conclusions:

- The programme takes 4 arguments, the number of people initially infected (`int infected`), the number of weeks the calculation must go on for (`int weeks`), the percentage of increase in the number of infections per week (`double inf`), and the percentage of deaths per week (`double de`).
- For every week, the programme, in a new line, displays the week number (`int w`), the number of people infected (`int infected`), and the number of deaths till that week.
- Every week, the infections are incremented by `inf`% of `infected` rounded off to the nearest whole number.
- The number of deaths till every week is equal to `de`% of `infected` rounded off to the nearest whole number.

Based on this analysis, you can write a simple programme like this which does the job as specified:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Infections
{
    public static void main(int infected, int weeks, double inf, double de) {
    /*
        Example values:

        infected = 100;
        weeks = 26;
        inf = 25.5;
        de = 3.5;
    */

        System.out.println("Week\tInfections\tDeaths");
        for (int w=1;w<=weeks;w++) {
            System.out.println(w+"\t"+infected+"\t"+(int)Math.round((de*infected)/100));
            infected += (int)Math.round((inf*infected)/100);
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend you to read the problem statement thoroughly and have a good understanding of what is supposed to be done before attempting to solve it. That way, you will be able to have the right approach to solving it.